# invalid api keys permission denied error in google api using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api

I am using google api first time my code execute perfectly even give me data using people service api...but second time it give me following error

> Type: Google_Service_Exception
>
> Message: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing
>   a valid API key.", "errors": [ { "message": "The request is missing a
>   valid API key.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ],
>   "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }

i am using codeignitor and this is redirected uri controller function...thanks in advance and sorry for poor english..

```
$client = $this->google_client_setup();
$client->authenticate($this->input->get('code'));
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
$people_service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);


$profile = $people_service->people->get(
    'people/me', array('personFields' => 'names,emailAddresses'));
$access_token = $access_token['access_token'];
$email = $profile['emailAddresses'][0]['value'];
$name =  $profile['names'][0]['displayName'];
$user = [
    'email' => $email,
    'name' => $name,
    'is_admin' => 0
];
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the controller and knowing how it's invoked, but it's very likely that you're not getting `code` via `GET` on the second run. That would cause `$client` to not get correctly set and then on everything that uses it would start behaving abnormally

Comment: but my code execute perfectly first time..i get this error when i refresh the page

Comment: that's my point exactly... it would appear that on the first run you are correctly passing the variables via `GET` but not when refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but I would think that if it says it's missing valid api key, you should treat that as answer ;)

Are you being redirected somewhere after first run? That could explain problem Javier commented on.

I'd suggest to dump two things to debug the code:

```
$this->input->get('code')
```

and if this is ok, then

```
$access_token
```

this should give you idea what your problem is :)

Good luck!

Comment: and both times they get set properly?